# How to get rid of : class type mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I hope to process various generic data sources accessed by `Kafka`, so I developed the following code:

```
  def accessKafkaSource[T: ClassTag](sEnv: StreamExecutionEnvironment): DataStream[T] = {
    val kafkaSource: KafkaSource[T] = KafkaSource.builder()
      .setBootstrapServers("")
      .setGroupId("")
      .setTopics("test")
      .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST))
      .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new AbstractDeserializationSchema[T]() {
        override def deserialize(msg: Array[Byte]): T = {
           // JSONUtil.toBean(StrUtil.str(msg, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), classOf[T])
           JSONUtil.toBean(StrUtil.str(msg, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), classTag[T].runtimeClass)
        }
      })
      .build()
```

Since the commented out code will get an error: class type required but t found, I modified the code, but caused a new problem: type mismatch; found : _$ 1 where type _$ 1 required: T。 How should my needs be realized?

Comment: Please try to provide the code directly rather than [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) with code, so people helping you may easy copy-paste your example and see what's wrong. People are more inclined to help when the question is easier to handle. Here are a few tips on how to ask [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AminMal notes, `runtimeClass` is not guaranteed to return the class object of `T`, just what it erases to in the runtime.  `AnyVal`s in particular will break this.

If everything you wish to deserialize is an `AnyRef` (this is likely the case), you can often safely cast the result of `runtimeClass`:

```scala
def kindaSafeClass[T <: AnyRef : ClassTag]: Class[T] = classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
```

The situation this would be unsafe is when generics are involved (erasure...), as can be seen by

```scala
val clazz = kindaSafeClass[List[String]]
val lst = List(1)

val cast =
  if (clazz.isInstance(lst)) {
    println(s"$lst is an instance of $clazz")
    clazz.cast(lst)
  } else ???

println(cast)
println(cast.head.isEmpty)
```

which will print `List(1) is an instance of class scala.collection.immutable.List`, then `List(1)`, and then blow up with a `ClassCastException` when we try to cast `1` to a `String`.

But if your `T` will always be an `AnyRef` and you can be sure that it's not generic, you can

```scala
// Note: T must not be generic (e.g. List[String])
def accessKafkaSource[T <: AnyRef : ClassTag](sEnv: StreamExecutionEnvironment): DataStream[T] =
  // as before until...
  JSONUtils.toBean(StrUtil.str(msg, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), kindaSafeClass[T])
  // as before...
```

Comment: Although I'm not a fan of `asInstanceOf` thing, but still upvoting this for the great explanations about runtime stuff.

Comment: Confession: it's adapted from a chat session with a couple of Scala compiler engineers.

Comment: Sometimes, if dealing with Java-oriented things (Flink definitely and Kafka arguably qualify) you have to resort to unspeakable things.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `runtimeClass` returns a `Class[_]`, not a `Class[T]`. This kind of approach would make perfect sense in Java, like:

```java
JSONUtils.toBean(whateverString, MyClass.class); // and so on
```

In Scala, (of course there are unsafe approaches to make this work) but if you're using some JSON library (like Play Json, circe, etc,.), you can do this:

```scala
// method signature would look something like this
def accessKafkaSource[T : Reads](sEnv: StreamExecutionEnvironment): DataStream[T] = {
// just going to write the deserialization part:
  override def deserialize(msg: Array[Byte]): T = {
    Json.parse(msg).as[T] // asOpt is safer, not going to get into exception handling and other stuff
  }
}
```

This behavior is also applicable to other json libraries in scala. Or if you have other kind of documents like xml, expect an implicit function from `Array[Byte] => DocumentType (Like JsValue, String, Xml, anything)`, and another one `DocumentType => T`. Because this function `accessKafkaSource` should not be responsible to figure out how data should be deserialized/serialized.

Comment: To elaborate, because there are types (specifically `AnyVal` types which get boxed), `runtimeClass` on `ClassTag` cannot return a `Class[_]`.  This can be seen by `classTag[Int].runtimeClass == (42: Any).getClass` evaluating to false.